# Yarn queue not taking full resources

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

My Cluster has 2 queues:
*`default`* - 50% and cannot go up.
*`important`* - 50% and can go beyond 50.
See my configuration below:

```
<configuration>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name><value>default,important</value></property>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity</name><value>100</value></property>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name><value>50</value>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.important.capacity</name><value>50</value>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity</name><value>50</value>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
<property><name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.support.user-limit-factor</name><value>2</value>
</configuration>
```

*The issue is that the `important` queue is not able to go beyond its dedicated capacity (especially vcores) when a single spark application is ran*

Comment: Can you show the YARN UI screenshot? What distribution it is(like Cloudera, EMR..)?

Comment: @san it is Cloudera distribution